# ImageMagick no longer works with threshold parameters on png images after ImageTragick patch

Tags: image-processing, terminal, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert

I have code that has been successfully monochroming (making black and white) images, for both jpg and pngs for awhile now. Recently I noticed that it is not longer working for pngs. When I run this for a png, I get an empty image with the correct dimensions. For a jpg I get correct result.

```
convert -density 150 -threshold '50'% -fuzz 1% -transparent white 'input.png' 'output.png'
```

I discovered it's the threshold that isn't working, when removed the image is no longer blank, but of course is no longer monochrome as well.

```
convert -density 150 -fuzz 1% -transparent white 'input.png' 'output.png'
```

I have found that converting the png to a jpg before running still results in a blank image.

```
convert 'input.png' 'input.jpg'
convert -density 150 -threshold '50'% -fuzz 1% -transparent white 'input.jpg' 'output.png'
```

I've also tried restructuring the command as suggested in the comments, but still getting the same results.

```
convert 'input.png' -threshold '50'% -transparent white 'output.png'
```

I tested this on an instance that doesn't have the [ImageTragick](https://imagetragick.com/) secuirty patch and it did not have this issue, so I am fairly confident that the issue arrived when I updated ImageMagick. I am currently using 7.0.2-0.

What is causing this behavior, and how can I use ImageMagick 7.0.2-0 Convert to monochrome a png image?

**Update:** as requested, here's one of the many png images I've used for testing.

[image]

Comment: "I believe this may be related to the "ImageTragick" patch I applied" don't you have anywhere to test this assumption - another installation or a friends setup?

Comment: @Bonzo I did as you suggested and was able to confirm the problem exists only post ImageTragick security patch.

Comment: That's a weird command to run! You can remove the `-density 150` as it will have no effect unless dealing with a PDF or vector image. You can also remove the `-fuzz 1%` because after a threshold your pixels will all be either pure white or pure black so there is no need for any fuzz at all. Also, consider moving your input image *before* the `-threshold` to fit the new commandline processing ordering.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did the changes to your command as suggested, ended up with `convert 'input.png' -threshold '50'% -transparent white 'output.png'
` and still getting the same behavior. Works for jpg, not for png.

Comment: Can you share the original PNG fie?

Comment: I've used about 12 very different pngs, none of them work. I'll update question with an example.

Comment: Not sure what is going on, but does this do what you want? `convert buckeroos.png -threshold 50% -alpha off -transparent white output.png`

Comment: Yes, yes it did. Perhaps it's the `escapeshellarg` and `escapeshellcmd` I run on the parameters and command which add those ' marks that are breaking it. Still unsure why it only breaks on png. Post this as an answer and I'll accept, also I'll bring this to the attention of ImageMagick.

Comment: Not keen to post as an answer as I don't understand what is causing it or why it works - I am hoping @GlennRanders-Pehrson may have some insights once aware... let's see if he has some time for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to MArk Setchell in the comments

> Not sure what is going on, but does this do what you want?

```
convert buckeroos.png -threshold 50% -alpha off -transparent white output.png
```

Perhaps it's the `escapeshellarg` and `escapeshellcmd` I run on the parameters and command which add those ' marks that are breaking it.